# Jail sftp user in nginx directory

Tags: debian, chroot, sftp

I have a small problem. I'm on Debian 7, i have made a new user with group. I need to make this user fully privileged and JAILED to directory **/usr/share/nginx**. 
When i want to connect to sftp there appears connection problem. 
This is because of set configuration of Match Group/Match User. Without of that connection is successfull but with "/" directory of system.

This is my sshd_config

Port - im connecting to right port

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User testsftp
    ChrootDirectory /usr/share/nginx
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match Group sftpgroup
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I have uncommented usePAM

Comment: It isn't that problem.

Comment: So update the question with the related information what is different than the other question and what in the answer did not work for you. What are the permissions on the **all path components** to the chroot directory? What errors do you see in sever log?